# Kentico CMS & Campaign Monitor

Tags: asp.net, newsletter, kentico

Just wondering if anyone has any pointers on how to integrate campaign monitor with Kentico CMS. Kentico has its own built in newsletter signup but I want campaign monitor to be updated when a user suscribes. I tried simply modifying the aspx page with a campaign monitor html form but when I try and submit an email address nothing happens.

When I view source kenitco is surrounding the page contentwith a form which I believe is affecting the CM form.

I have tried adding a static html page but the form action is somehow being modified to point to the active page instead of pointing to Campaign monitor subscription page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this. The problem was that aspx pages do not allow you to submit a form other than to itself.  I modified the template to be a asp page and it now serves the form fine.

This maynot be the best solution but works for me!